# Calculating relative location in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, location, transformation, coordinate

I am doing some projects about Augmented Reality(actually, Mixed Reality), and I'm having some difficulty about this.

I use a camera using mobile application and recognizes the number plate of the car in real-time. When the number plate is recognized, it calculates the virtual location of number plate and displays virtual object in the exact location where the light is, using AR/MR. It should still track and display it even if affined or rotated.

I am using Unity & OpenCV for Unity.

So my actual question is: I want to know if there is any methodology for automatically tracking the relative location of the light, using the location of targeted object(here it is a number plate). Is there any algorithm?

Comment: I am not an expert at all but I guess you can : 1°) Detect the 2 uppermost and 2 lowest points of the plate ; 2°) Determine a plane with dimensions + center ; 3°) Calculate a vector from the center of the plane to the mid-point of the top edge of the plane ; 4°) Determine approximate position of the lights with the direction vector given step 3°) + normal of the plane

Comment: You mention "The relative location of the light"... which light?

Comment: I mean the light at the front side of the car